# Count instances of value in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to write a query that returns the count of a given value across multiple tables.

Right now, I'm using the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SL,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [Sales Line Archive]
  WHERE [Document No_] = 123
) AS SLA
FROM [Sales Line]
WHERE [Document No_] = 123
```

Which returns a single result with the count of lines in Sales Line in the first column and the count from Sales Line Archive in the second.

However, I'd like to request multiple records using an `IN` clause, so that I could get results like the following

```
Document No_, SL, SLA
1, 3, 0
2, 0, 4
3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to pivot

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT [Document No_], 'SL' AS Source
FROM [Sales Line]
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Document No_], 'SLA' AS Source
FROM [Sales Line Archive]
) 
SELECT P.[Document No_],
       P.SL,
       P.SLA
FROM CTE
PIVOT (COUNT(Source) FOR Source IN ([SL], [SLA])) P
WHERE P.[Document No_] IN (1,2,3);
```

I'd hope that the predicate on `[Document No_]` gets pushed up into the selects from the source tables. Check the execution plans to be sure.

Comment: It does! Thanks a ton. I've never worked with `PIVOT` before, so I'm definitely going to explore its uses.

Comment: Full join using PIVOT? Didn't expect that.

Comment: @AndriyM An actual `full outer join` of the two aggregated partial results could be more efficient as they could come out of a stream aggregate ordered and go into a merge full outer join.